# How can I enable natural scrolling for my trackpad, but disable it for my mouse?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mouse, macos

Is there a way to enable natural scrolling on the trackpad, but disable it for mouse?

I think that natural scrolling does make sense on a trackpad, but with a mouse it doesn't feel natural at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)

[image]